# Check when task starts / shuts down

Tags: c#, process

I wanted to know how I could read from the taskmanager whether a task has started / been shut down. The way I thought about it is, that I'd have a loop, which constantly checks, whether a new task has started and search for a specific string within the task-manager. Though this is possible, I didn't really want to use that method, because it would "eat" a lot of performance, I think and so I wanted to ask, if you have a way to check, if a program has started / shut down. This is how I thought about it:

```
    while(!"notepad.exe found")
    {
       SearchForTask("notepad.exe");
       if(notepad.exe found)
         //Do Something
    }
```

If there is another way, please let me know.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking for a running process is easy:

```
 if(Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad").Length == 0)
 {
    // "notepad" not running
 } else {
    // At least one "notepad" process is running
 }
```

You can also check for `Length` being greater than zero, or store the amount of running processes the last time you checked and see if it's different (if less than the last amount, one of the processes closed, if more, one started), since you can actually have more than one "notepad" running.

This uses the "friendly name" (generally, the executable name without the `exe` or path), if you are interested on a very specific process with a very specific path, then you'd need to iterate through the array that `GetProcessesByName` returns.

If you are doing this in a loop, I'd leave some free time on the loop so you are not checking constantly (that'd depend on what you are doing with all of this), otherwise you can use a timer (one of the many available) and poll every 'n' milliseconds.

Comment: but wouldn't that force me to use a "while" again, because that, what you just posted there is a check for one-time, isn't it? Am I wrong? I'd rather not want to use a loop, because it takes a lot of memory.

Comment: Loops don't use memory, they use cpu. You can use a timer if you prefer, or use a task and add a delay in the loop to free the cpu. What you prefer

Comment: Sorry for using the wrong words, I'm not very experienced in that. I think I will go for the timer. What time wouldn't "kill" the computer. If I searched for a process every 10 seconds, would that have a tiny lagspike every 10 seconds or is it such a tiny function, that it won't really mind?

Comment: If you are just looking for a process, you could probably do that many times in one second without noticeable delay in any relatively modern cpu